# How to make Vim detect filetype from the shebang line?

Tags: bash, vim, file-type

Sometimes I write scripts without any filename extension. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log('hello world!');
```

I hope that Vim can detect the filetype from the shebang line (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env node` is `javascript`). What should I put into `filetype.vim`?

Comment: Why not add a second or last line modeline `# vim: ft=javascript` since Vim already checks for the modeline rather than reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @SwaroopCH Why not parse the information from a line already in the file that has the necessary information, like any [real editor](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) has done for years, rather than repeating it redundantly in an editor specific fashion that junks up the file for users of other editors? */me dons flame suit*

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Following the instructions listed in [`:help new-filetype-scripts`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#new-filetype-scripts),
create the `scripts.vim` file in the user runtime directory (`~/.vim/`
on Unix-like systems), and write the following script in it:

```
if did_filetype()
    finish
endif
if getline(1) =~# '^#!.*/bin/env\s\+node\>'
    setfiletype javascript
endif
```

Comment: See also the whole `:help new-filetype` section which is worth reading.

Comment: why doesn't the forward slashes be escaped?
/bin/env

Comment: @LaiYu-Hsuan:  A forward slash character is not a special symbol according to syntax of Vim regular expressions.  It could be escaped as `\/`, of course, but it is necessary only for patterns that are used in a forward search command (`/`) or in a substitution command (`:s`) when pattern delimiters are slashes.

Comment: You can also put these lines inside `.vimrc` by using `autocmd`, probably `bufread` is the one, to fire the function.

Answer (score 11):

create this file `~/.vim/ftdetect/node.vim`
with this contents

```
fun! s:DetectNode()
    if getline(1) == '#!/usr/bin/env node'
        set ft=javascript
    endif
endfun

autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * call s:DetectNode()
```

Comment: actually, "ft=javascript" is much more likely to work.  Most people DO have "javascript" defined and DON'T have "node" defined.

Comment: for those that prefer it on a single line: `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * if getline(1) == '#!/usr/bin/env node' | set ft=javascript | endif`

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in a plugin, one does exist for this:

https://github.com/vitalk/vim-shebang

This contains a pattern for `node -> javascript` highlighting.

```
AddShebangPattern! javascript ^#!.*\s\+node\>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but [Node.vim](https://github.com/moll/vim-node) handles detecting such JavaScript files for you. And then some. :-)