# Syntax highlighting not looking at shebang line on known filetypes

Tags: vim

I have a Perl file with an atypical naming convention (e.g. file = test.cfg) and *.cfg is a known file extension for an existing filetype in my vim install.  Is there a vimrc setting that will tell vim to use the shebang value, regardless of the file extension?  I know I can put `# vim: set filetype=perl :` in the file itself as an alternate solution.  I want vim to look @ the shebang value first, then the file extension.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $var = "please highlight me";
```

Comment: The standard name for that “header value” is “[shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line” or “hashbang line”. Thus, answers to this question will be the same as to [How to make Vim detect filetype from shebang line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8890668/578288), unless something specific needs to be done to override a wrong extension as opposed to the file having no extension.

Comment: Rory, my problem is that `*.cfg` is detected as a different filetype.  Vim detects filetype automatically if the file extension does not match an existing syntax (e.g. file is called `tmp.foobar123`).

I've edited the title based on your feedback, thanks!

Comment: I see; if I set up a `~/.vim/scripts.vim` file like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8891619/578288) on “How to make Vim detect filetype from shebang line?”, it does help highlight unknown files, but it does not override the [`'filetype'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27filetype%27) of files whose extensions are already associated with a filetype.

Comment: I think [`:help syntax-loading`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#syntax-loading) will be helpful when looking for where to put syntax-setting commands so they are run in the right order. It says that [`:filetype on`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#:filetype) is what sets up the setting of `'filetype'` based on the file extension. Maybe the solution is to add another [`BufReadPost`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#BufReadPost) autocommand that overrides the current `'filetype'` with the shebang line’s filetype if there is one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, the static file pattern comparison (in `filetype.vim`) is run before the detection based on contents (in `scripts.vim`), but since it's all Vimscript, nothing prevents you from messing with that order.

If this is just about the `.cfg` extension and Perl scripts, put the following into `~/.vim/filetype.vim`:

```
if exists('did_load_filetypes')
    finish
endif

augroup filetypedetect
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.cfg        if getline(1) =~# '^#!/usr/bin/perl\>' | setf perl | endif
augroup END
```

Comment: Thanks Ingo, this worked for my immediate issue.  I'll play around with the *.vim file loading order to see if I can get Vim to do this for the generic case.

Comment: I think all you have to do to make it more generic is replace "*.cfg" with "*".

Comment: Yep, that works for a more general case.  I'll add a few more lines for common file syntaxes.